# Expand table view cell to the content's height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textview, swift5

My ViewController has a tableView inside it, and every cell within the tableView has a textView that displays poems. Some poems are long and some are short. I made some code to expand the UITableViewCell when tapped so that the user could focus on reading only one poem and the other ones would be hidden.

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var poemasTableView: UITableView!
    var selectedRowIndex = -1

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {
            return 240 //Expanded
        }
        return 55 //Not expanded
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if selectedRowIndex == indexPath.row {
            selectedRowIndex = -1
        } else {
            selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
```

It is working fine, however I want to do something else. When the cell is tapped, I want it to expand in order to fit the content of the textView. So, for example, if a poem is too large than the new height should be 320 but if it is shorter, it should be 150 and so on.

How could I do this?

Comment: First, is there a reason you're using `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`? Second, have you tried search? There are lots of similar questions and answers here, as well as many, many examples out on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the bounding box of the complete poem using `boundingRectWithSize`. And then you would assign the calculated height to the height of the row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {
        // Expanded
        let poem: String = poems[indexPath.row]
        let size = CGSize(width: poemasTableView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let rectangle: CGRect = NSString(string: poem).boundingRect(with: size,
                             options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                             attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)],
                             context: nil)
        let maximum_height: CGFloat = 1366
        let rowHeight: CGFloat = min(rectangle.height, maximum_height)
        return rowHeight
    }
    return 55 //Not expanded
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I am still having an issue. Since I am using firebase and coreData in my app, instead of poems I would use "arrayPoemas", which is of type "Poemas" and not of type String. So an error appears in the line "let poem: String" because it cannot convert type "Poemas" to type String. And if I erase that ":String" it won't let me use the initializer"NSString()". How could i fix this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Core Data, but I think it would be `let poem: String = (arrayPoemas[indexPath.row].value(forKeyPath: "text") as? String) ?? ""`, asumming `text` is the field of your Poem entity that contains the poem's text.

Comment: I tried using the code but there's a problem. I don't know why when I press the UITableViewCell it is expanding all of them to a certain height(I think 320) and not to the content's height.

Comment: From your question I understand that you want a maximum height, in case that the poem is really long. 320 is actually somewhat small, so I updated the code to specify a maximum height of 1366. Let me know if it works.